# Google Maps JS v3 and HTML5 JavaScript Frameworks

Tags: javascript, google-maps, backbone.js, google-maps-api-3, ember.js

I'm currently working on a mapping project using the Google Maps JavaScript API.

But my application will be much more advanced then showing a single map and will eventually show multiple map "views" as well as options to manipulate the map using forms on the page.

I have used a couple different HTML 5 JavaScript frameworks such as Backbone.js, Angular.js as well as Ember.js for other projects but nothing has worked well with Google Maps.

I'm wondering if anyone would recommend using a particular JavaScript framework for working with Google Maps JavaScript v3 API.
Preferably something with an active plugin/module for Google Maps would work best. I have created my own special views in Backbone for Google Maps but it does not work as "well" as I want it to.

If you have a suggestion to use a different mapping API, other than GMaps, I would love to hear about it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there are two really great approaches.

1. EmberJS + Leaflet  http://gabesmed.github.io/ember-leaflet/
2. AngularJS + Leaflet  http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/
3. AngularJS + Google Maps  http://nlaplante.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/usage

I have decided to either use AngularJS or EmberJS with Leaflet, as the Leaflet API is much more robust than the Google Maps API. (imo)

Answer (score 3):

There is also an ember-leaflet proyect, seems interesting but I did not taste it yet.

https://github.com/gabesmed/ember-leaflet

http://gabesmed.github.io/ember-leaflet/

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is exactly what I needed. 

Leaflet allows for any tiles to be used as the background. Whether it is Google Maps or not this will work amazingly.

Ember is a great framework that, while I am still trying to wrap my head around it, works great for scaling applications.

The ember-leaflet project, while a little new ties it all in together very well.

Comment: I'm working on a similar project for a while, I learned leaflet and ember in this later months, I have code in production, but is not very neat and I'm refactoring all the thing an sure I will use ember-leaflet

Answer (score 1):

Not a Google maps solution, but you said you'd love to hear about other possible mapping solutions.  Well, ArcGIS has a Javascript API https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/ that is directly coupled with the Dojo javascript framework, though they do have a light version of the API as well that still runs off a stripped down version of dojo, but is more aimed at allowing integration with other JS frameworks.

May or may not meet what you're wanting, but it's an option anyway and figured I'd pass it along.  They have a number of samples and such so I'd suggest you go there and take a look rather than me trying to explain.

Answer (score 1):

I second the ember-leaflet suggestion. You can use any map provider you want, through leaflet.